# Building minimal R package fails without explanation on Windows

Tags: r, package

Using R studio, I start a new R project. *Building* the built-in "Hello, world" example works fine. But when I try to *check* the package I get this:

```
* using log directory 'C:/D-data/projects/mypackage.Rcheck'
* using R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
* using platform: i386-w64-mingw32 (32-bit)
* using session charset: ISO8859-1
* using option '--as-cran'
* checking for file 'mypackage/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package 'mypackage' version '0.1'
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking whether package 'mypackage' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
See 'C:/D-data/projects/mypackage.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR
Warning: running command '"C:/R/R-3.2.2/bin/i386/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL -l "C:/D-data/projects/mypackage.Rcheck" --no-html "C:\D-data\projects\mypackage.Rcheck\00_pkg_src\mypackage"' had status 1

See
  'C:/D-data/projects/mypackage.Rcheck/00check.log'
for details.

Error: Command failed (1)
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

But when I run the command that supposedly failed in the command prompt, it works fine:

```
* DONE (mypackage)
```

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] datasets  utils     grDevices graphics  grid      stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] mypackage_0.1   ecb_0.1         readr_0.1.1     magrittr_1.5    tidyr_0.2.0     rvest_0.2.0     gridExtra_2.0.0 RCurl_1.95-4.7 
 [9] bitops_1.0-6    httr_1.0.0      knitr_1.11      dplyr_0.4.2     MASS_7.3-43     lubridate_1.3.3 RODBC_1.3-12    scales_0.2.5   
[17] ggthemes_2.2.1  stringr_1.0.0   plyr_1.8.3      Hmisc_3.16-0    Formula_1.2-1   survival_2.38-3 lattice_0.20-33 ggplot2_1.0.1  
[25] reshape2_1.4.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  digest_0.6.8        R6_2.1.1            splines_3.2.2       assertthat_0.1      munsell_0.4.2      
 [7] proto_0.3-10        nnet_7.3-10         acepack_1.3-3.3     DBI_0.3.1           stringi_0.5-5       gtable_0.1.2       
[13] colorspace_1.2-6    foreign_0.8-66      tools_3.2.2         parallel_3.2.2      cluster_2.0.3       memoise_0.2.1      
[19] rpart_4.1-10        Rcpp_0.12.0         latticeExtra_0.6-26
```

Comment: Why are you not using 64bit-R? What is the content of 00check.log?

Comment: The content of 00check.log is identical to the first set of output above. And I use 32-bit because 64-bit doesn't play nice with my ODBC. In any case, I get the identical error when using 64-bit R.